# Pandas groupby + ngroup in pipes

Tags: pandas

I can create a unique value for a set of columns using `ngroup()` (mimicking R's `group_indicdes` or Stata's `group()`) using:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,1,2,2,2],'b':[1,1,2,1,1,2]})
df['idx'] = df.groupby(['a', 'b']).ngroup()
```

I cannot seem to get this to work in a piped solution:

```
df = df.groupby(['a','b']).agg(newID= pd.NamedAgg(column=['a','b'], aggfunc='ngroup'))
```

Comment: ``df.assign(idx=df.groupby(["a", "b"]).ngroup())``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df = df.assign(newID = df.groupby(['a', 'b']).ngroup())
print (df)    
   a  b  idx  newID
0  1  1    0      0
1  1  1    0      0
2  1  2    1      1
3  2  1    2      2
4  2  1    2      2
5  2  2    3      3
```

Your solution should be changed with unpacking by `**` with any column, because `ngroup` is counts from parameter `by`:

```
df = df.assign(**df.groupby(['a','b']).agg(newID= ('a', 'ngroup')))
print (df)    
   a  b  idx  newID
0  1  1    0      0
1  1  1    0      0
2  1  2    1      1
3  2  1    2      2
4  2  1    2      2
5  2  2    3      3
```